# Node.js Mongoose replace order of passed arguments in findeOne() callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I want to use Mongoose in order to save my passport oAuth record to database or ignore it when it's already there. However my then() callback function switch the order of passed arguments and puts results of the query instead of error.

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: confKeys.googleAuth.client_id,
    clientSecret: confKeys.googleAuth.client_secret,
    callbackURL: confKeys.googleAuth.redirect_uris[0]
  },(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        User.findOne({ googleID: profile.id }).then((err, existingUser) => {
            console.log(existingUser) // here I get undefined even if user exists in database
            console.log(err)// here I get data for the user
            if(existingUser){
                done(err, existingUser);
            }else{
                console.log('new user');
                new User({googleID: profile.id}).save()
                .then((err,user) => done(err, user));
            };
        });
  }
));
```

In documentation error argument should be first and result of the query second. I cannot just change names for arguments and get over since passport would give me a promise error. How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises only pass ONE argument to their `.then()` callback like this:

```
User.findOne({ googleID: profile.id }).then(existingUser => { ...});
```

If there's an error, then the promise rejects which you catch separately with a `.catch()` method like this:

```
User.findOne({ googleID: profile.id }).then(existingUser => {  
    console.log(existingUser);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

You could use that in your code like this:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: confKeys.googleAuth.client_id,
    clientSecret: confKeys.googleAuth.client_secret,
    callbackURL: confKeys.googleAuth.redirect_uris[0]
  },(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        User.findOne({ googleID: profile.id }).then(existingUser => {
            console.log(existingUser);
            if(existingUser){
                return existingUser;
            } else {
                console.log('new user');
                return new User({googleID: profile.id}).save();
            };
        }).then(user => {
             done(null, user);
        }).catch(err => {
             done(err);
        });
  }
));
```

Though, generally it's messy to start with promises and turn them back into regular callbacks.  You'd like to use promises all the way through (simpler error propagation).